# Mysql do a query if case 1, do another query if case 2

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I need a query for SCD2 in MySQL using:

DATA STRUCTURE:
`id, data, start_date, end_date`

if the record_id exist:

-update the record's end_date,

-and create a new record with the new data

else:

-insert a new record.

Can I use MySQL CASE to this?

Comment: 'and create a new record with the new data'- I am not clear what you mean- it looks like you would be creating a duplicate , can you clarify by example please.

Comment: Dear Salmon, there are two cases: 1. insert a new record, 2. update the existing record's end_date field, AND insert a new record.
For example, there is a table about repairers. If I'd like to update one's address, bu I'd like to store his old address, I update the existing record's end_date, and insert a new record with the new address. Thus I can find his old address with an expired end_date, and his new address with a non existing end_date. In one word I'd like to store historical data.

Comment: You might be able to just use `REPLACE INTO` syntax but you'll need to add a trigger if. you want to create a new record on an update.

Comment: Actually, reading your last comment, I would change that to an INSERT INTO with
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.  But you will still need the trigger

Comment: If you wish to store BOTH historic and current data in the same table then you cannot do this with one query (and a trigger), you could do so using an insert and an update within a transaction. It is more usual to store historic data in a separate table (mostly for performance reasons) , if you wish to do that a single insert..on duplicate key with a trigger would do assuming a duplicate key can be established.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need an end-date to store historic data;
Whenever you want to store a new address, you simply add it with the start-date.
You retrieve history by
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY start-date
Or just the last address by
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY start-date DESC LIMIT 1